# Catching event when selecting multiple charts in a worksheet

Tags: vba, events, charts

I want to catch the event when selecting several charts in a worksheet. Is their an event handler to achieve this in Excel VBA?

I have managed to catch events on application level with the class *AppEvents* and for all the charts in a worksheets with the class *ChartEvents*.
The events catcher is started with *AppEventsStart* which opens the form *ufEvents*. The form displays the selected object name or selected range address and logs all events in a listbox. The event catcher is ended with *AppEventsEnd* or by closing the form.

Code Module **mEvents**

```
Public App As AppEvents
Public Cht As New ChartEvents
Public Chts() As New ChartEvents

'*** Application *********************

'*** Activate Application event catcher
Public Sub AppEventsStart()
    Set App = New AppEvents
    ChartEventsStart
    Load ufEvents
    ufEvents.Show vbModeless
End Sub

'*** Deactivate Application event catcher
Public Sub AppEventsEnd()
    Set App = Nothing
    ChartEventsEnd
    Unload ufEvents
End Sub

'*** Charts *********************

'*** Activate Chart event catcher
Sub ChartEventsStart()
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Dim i As Integer

    'only initialize when there are charts in sheet
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim Chts(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count - 1)

        i = 0
        For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects            
            Set Chts(i).EventChart = chtObj.Chart
            i = i + 1
        Next chtObj
    End If
End Sub

'*** Deactivate Chart event catcher
Sub ChartEventsEnd()
    Dim i As Integer

    'single chart in sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Cht.EventChart = Nothing

    'multiple charts in sheet
    For i = 0 To UBound(Chts)        
        Set Chts(i).EventChart = Nothing
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Class **AppEvents**

```
Private WithEvents EventApp As Excel.Application

'*** Starting application event catcher
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set EventApp = ActiveWorkbook.Application
End Sub

'*** When activating a sheet
Private Sub EventApp_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)
    ChartEventsStart
    ufEvents.Update "Activated sheet " & sh.Name
End Sub

'*** When deactivating a sheet
Private Sub EventApp_SheetDeactivate(ByVal sh As Object)
    ChartEventsEnd
    ufEvents.Update "Dectivated sheet " & sh.Name
End Sub

'*** When changing tha range selection in a sheet
Private Sub EventApp_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ufEvents.Update "Changed selection in sheet " & sh.Name
End Sub

'*** When changing the content in a sheet
Private Sub EventApp_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ufEvents.Update "Changed sheet " & sh.Name
End Sub
```

Class **ChartEvents**

```
Public WithEvents EventChart As Chart

'*** When activating a chart
Private Sub EventChart_Activate()
    ufEvents.Update "Activated chart " & ActiveChart.Parent.Name
End Sub

'*** When deactivating a chart
Private Sub EventChart_Deactivate()
    ufEvents.Update "Deactivated chart " & EventChart.Parent.Name
End Sub

'*** When clicking the mouse on a chart
Private Sub EventChart_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    ufEvents.Update "Mouse down on chart " & EventChart.Parent.Name
End Sub

'*** When changing the selection in a chart
Private Sub EventChart_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)
    ufEvents.Update "Changed selection in chart " & ActiveChart.Parent.Name
End Sub
```

Userform **ufEvents**

```
'*** Update form with last event and and selected object name
Public Sub Update(Optional ByVal lastEvent As String = vbNullString)

    'add and last event in listbox and select it
    If lastEvent <> vbNullString Then
        lbxLog.AddItem lastEvent
        lbxLog.ListIndex = lbxLog.ListCount - 1
    End If

    'display selected range address
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        txtSelection.Value = "Range " & Selection.Address

    'display selected object name
    Else
        txtSelection.Value = TypeName(Selection)
    End If
End Sub

'*** End event catcher when closing form
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    AppEventsEnd
End Sub
```

When several charts are selected the statement *TypeName(Selection)* returns **DrawingObjects**, thus I know when I have selected multiple charts.

I expected *_Activate* or *_MouseDown* to execute, when selecting at least one more chart with **Ctrl** and **Left mouse click**. This does not happen. In fact, no event is caught anymore when at least two charts are selected.

I have tried to create a class similar to ChartEvents for e.g. shapes with

```
Public WithEvents obj As Shape
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

Is there an event handler in Excel VBA to catch, when changing the selection of multiple charts?

Thanks in advance for your support!
Immanuel

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a event handler for changing the selection of multiple charts, because it looks like Excel goes in Edit Mode after selecting more than one chart.

You could (as a workaround and when it suits your purpose) ad a few lines of code to make sure there's only 1 chart activated/selected.

Change your EventChart_Deactivate as follows; (setting the visible property to False and back to True deselects it)

```
   Private Sub EventChart_Deactivate()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(EventChart.Parent.Name).Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(EventChart.Parent.Name).Visible = True
    ufEvents.Update "Deactivated chart " & EventChart.Parent.Name
    If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ActiveChart.Parent.Name).Activate 
    End Sub
```